# Minimal degree of a polynomial such that $|p(z_1)| > |p(z_2)|, |p(z_3)|, ..., |p(z_n)|$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, plane-geometry, computational-geometry

I was investigating the behavior of $p(x)^n \mod {q(x)}$, for some polynomials $p, q \in \mathbb{C}[x]$. We'll assume $q$ is squarefree. If $q(x) = (x - z_1) (x - z_2) (x - z_3) ... (x - z_n)$ for complex $z_1, z_2, ..., z_n$, then using the CRT for polynomials we can see the behavior of $p(x)^n \mod {q(x)}$ is dominated by $p(z_i)^n$ if $|p(z_i)|$ is a unique maximum of $|p(z_1)|, |p(z_2)|, ..., |p(z_n)|$. I am interested in the minimum degree required for $p$ for that to happen for a particular root. That is:

Given $n$ different complex numbers, $z_1, z_2, ..., z_n$, what is the minimal degree of a polynomial $p$ such that $|p(z_1)| > |p(z_2)|, |p(z_3)|, ..., |p(z_n)|$?

Alternatively, this can be formulated geometrically by factoring $p$: given $n$ different points on the plane $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$, what is the minimal number of points you need to choose such that the product of the distance between $p_i$ and each of the chosen points is maximal for $p_1$?

Is this a known problem?

Some observations:

If $p_1$ is on the convex hull, then there's a point who is farthest from $p_1$, so the answer is $1$. If all of $z_1, z_2, ..., z_n$ are real (or slightly more generally, collinear), we can take the polynomial $C - (x - z_1)^2$ for large enough $C$, so the answer is $2$. In any case the answer is at most $n-1$, which can be achieved by taking $p_2, p_3, ..., p_n$.

I believe a degree of $n-1$ can be required, for example if $z_1 = 0$ and $z_2 ,..., z_n$ are the $n-1$-th roots of unity, but I don't have a proof of this. Is this correct?

This problem can be formulated as a system of polynomial (quadratic) inequalities over the reals, so it can be solved using CAD (iterate over degrees, check if there is a solution), but that is very inefficient. Is there a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if $z_1=0$ and other points form a regular $(n-1)$-gon centered at 0, then whenever $\deg p<n-1$ we have $$p(z_1)=\frac1{n-1}\sum_{k=2}^n p(z_k),$$
thus $|p(z_1)|$ can not not be maximal.